# use min or max with active record

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I am trying to get a min value from our database with the query below:

```
@supplier = Supplier.joins(:products).where('suppliers.permalink = ?', params[:id]).group('suppliers.id','products.id','products.name',min(variants.price)).pluck('products.id','products.name','suppliers.id',min(variants.price))
```

when I run what I believe the query should be, I get this result:

```
SELECT suppliers.id as supp_id, products.id as prod_id, products.name as prod_name, min(price) as low_price, max(price) as high_price from suppliers
  INNER JOIN variant_suppliers on variant_suppliers.supplier_id = suppliers.id
  INNER JOIN variants on variants.id = variant_suppliers.variant_id
  INNER JOIN products on products.id = variants.product_id
WHERE suppliers.id in (1,2)
GROUP BY suppliers.id, products.name, products.id;
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how to get this to work with the active record system instead of straight sql